# Access and preserve list names in lapply function

Tags: r, names, lapply

I need to access list names inside the lapply function. I've found some threads online where it's said I should iterate through the names of the list to be able to fetch each list element name in my function:

```
> n = names(mylist)
> mynewlist = lapply(n, function(nameindex, mylist) { return(mylist[[nameindex]]) }, mylist)
> names(mynewlist)
NULL
> names(mynewlist) = n
```

The problem is that mynewlist loses the original mylist indexes and I have to add that last names() assignment to restore them.

Is there a way to give an explicit index name to each element returned by the lapply function? Or a different way to make sure mynewlist elements have the correct index names set? I feel mynewlist index names could be wrong if lapply does not return the list elements in the same order than mylist.

Comment: I keep coming back to this post. Following the answers below, you can directly assign the list items as names via ```n <- names(mylist) %>% `names<-`(c(.))``` after loading dplyr.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I believe that `lapply` by default keeps the names attribute of whatever you are iterating over. When you store the names of `myList` in `n`, that vector no longer has any "names". So if you add that back in via,

```
names(n) <- names(myList)
```

and the use `lapply` as before, you should get the desired result.

**Edit**

My brains a bit foggy this morning. Here's another, perhaps more convenient, option:

```
sapply(n,FUN = ...,simplify = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

I was groping about, confused that `lapply` didn't have a `USE.NAMES` argument, and then I actually looked at the code for `sapply` and realized I was being silly, and this was probably a better way to go.

Comment: Yep, this works. I still have to create 'n' though via n = names(myList). Two calls to names(myList), once to create n, the second to set n attributes.

Comment: You could replace the second with `names(n) <- n` though.

Comment: @RobertKubrick See my edit for a possibly nicer solution. Examine the code for `sapply` to see just how simple this is; it's just acting as a wrapper that adds the names in after the fact.

Comment: @joran I used sapply and was able to output. But could you explain why you said "and then I actually looked at the code for `sapply` and realized I was being silly"? So why doesn't `lapply` have `USE.NAMES`?

Comment: I had been avoiding `sapply` because of the unpredictable type changing, but, looking at `sapply` source, it seems it is safe if `simplify` is `FALSE`. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply?rq=1  Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

the `setNames` function is a useful shortcut here

```
mylist <- list(a = TRUE, foo = LETTERS[1:3], baz = 1:5)
n <- names(mylist)
mynewlist <- lapply(setNames(n, n), function(nameindex) {mylist[[nameindex]]})
```

which preserves the names

```
> mynewlist
$a
[1] TRUE

$foo
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$baz
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: How do you pass the 'mylist' into the function?

Comment: @rmf Strictly speaking, you don't pass `mylist`. It is referenced inside the anonymous function in the `lapply`, but that reference is into the enclosing environment.

Answer (score 9):

Building on joran's answer, and precising it:

The `sapply(USE.NAMES=T)` wrapper will indeed set as names of the final result the values of the vector you are iterating over (and not its names attribute like lapply), **but only if these are characters.**

As a result, passing indices will not help. If you want to pass indexes with `sapply`, you need to resort to some (ugly) casting:

```
sapply(as.character(c(1,11)), function(i) TEST[[as.numeric(i)]], USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

In this case, a cleaner solution is to directly set and use names of your original object. Here is an exhaustive list of solutions:

```
TEST <- as.list(LETTERS[1:12])

### lapply ##
## Not working because no name attribute
lapply(c(1,11), function(i) TEST[[i]])

## working but cumbersome
index <- c(1,11)
names(index) <- index
lapply(index, function(i) TEST[[i]])

### sapply ##
## Not working because vector elements are not strings
sapply(c(1,11), function(i) TEST[[i]], simplify = F) 

## Working with the casting trick
sapply(as.character(c(1,11)), function(i) TEST[[as.numeric(i)]], simplify = F)

## Cleaner, using names with sapply:
names(TEST) <- LETTERS[26:15] 
sapply(names(TEST)[c(1,11)], function(name) TEST[[name]], simplify = F)
```

Answer (score 9):

`imap()` from the `purrr` package is nice for your problem.

```
library(purrr)
mylist <- list(foo1=1:10,foo2=11:20)
imap(mylist, function(x, y) mean(x)) ## x is the value, y is the name
```

or you can use a more compact version of imap:

```
imap(mylist, ~ mean(.x))
```

Note that you can use variations of imap_xxx depending on the type of vector you want:

```
imap_dbl(mylist, ~ mean(.x)) ## will return a named numeric vector.
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into `llply()` from the package `plyr`?

It does exactly what you are asking for. *For each element of a list, apply function, keeping results as a list. **llply is equivalent to lapply except that it will preserve labels** and can display a progress bar.* from `?llply`

```
mylist <- list(foo1=1:10,foo2=11:20)
>names(mylist)
[1] "foo1" "foo2"
newlist<- llply(mylist, function(x) mean(x))

>names(newlist)
[1] "foo1" "foo2"
```

Comment: Hmm.  That looks like exactly what `lapply` does.  See for example `lapply(mylist, mean)` and `llply(names(mylist), function(x) mean(mylist[[x]]))`.  Any ideas what "preserve labels" means?

Comment: I think `mlply` would do this

Answer (score 1):

Also building on @joran's answer, you can write a wrapper function that preserves object attributes such as below:

```
lapply_preserve_names <- function(list, fun){
  lapply(seq_along(list), function(i) {
    obj = list[i]
    names(obj) = names(list)[i]
    fun(obj)
  })
}
```

then instead of using lapply, simply use `lapply_preserve_names(your_list, function)`