# Why is `vapply` safer than `sapply`?

Tags: r, apply, r-faq

The documentation says

> `vapply` is similar to `sapply`, but has a pre-specified type of return value, so it can be safer [...] to use.

Could you please elaborate as to why it is generally safer, maybe providing examples?

---

P.S.: I know the answer and I already tend to avoid `sapply`. I just wish there was a nice answer here on SO so I can point my coworkers to it. Please, no "read the manual" answer.

Comment: It's more predictable, making the code less ambiguous, and more robust. Particularly in larger projects, say a large package, this is relevant.

Comment: The vapply manual examples for FUN.VALUE are very complex and intimidating for sapply users.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As has already been noted, `vapply` does two things:

- Slight speed improvement
- Improves consistency by providing limited return type checks.

The second point is the greater advantage, as it helps catch errors before they happen and leads to more robust code.  This return value checking could be done separately by using `sapply` followed by `stopifnot` to make sure that the return values are consistent with what you expected, but `vapply` is a little easier (if more limited, since custom error checking code could check for values within bounds, etc.).

Here's an example of `vapply` ensuring your result is as expected.  This parallels something I was just working on while PDF scraping, where `findD` would use a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to match a pattern in raw text data (e.g. I'd have a list that was `split` by entity, and a regex to match addresses within each entity.  Occasionally the PDF had been converted out-of-order and there would be two addresses for an entity, which caused badness).

```
> input1 <- list( letters[1:5], letters[3:12], letters[c(5,2,4,7,1)] )
> input2 <- list( letters[1:5], letters[3:12], letters[c(2,5,4,7,15,4)] )
> findD <- function(x) x[x=="d"]
> sapply(input1, findD )
[1] "d" "d" "d"
> sapply(input2, findD )
[[1]]
[1] "d"

[[2]]
[1] "d"

[[3]]
[1] "d" "d"

> vapply(input1, findD, "" )
[1] "d" "d" "d"
> vapply(input2, findD, "" )
Error in vapply(input2, findD, "") : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[3]]) result is length 2
```

Because two there are two d's in the third element of input2, vapply produces an error.  But sapply changes the class of the output from a character vector to a list, which could break code downstream.

As I tell my students, part of becoming a programmer is changing your mindset from "errors are annoying" to "errors are my friend."

**Zero length inputs**
One related point is that if the input length is zero, `sapply` will always return an empty list, regardless of the input type.  Compare:

```
sapply(1:5, identity)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
sapply(integer(), identity)
## list()    
vapply(1:5, identity, integer(1))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
vapply(integer(), identity, integer(1))
## integer(0)
```

With `vapply`, you are guaranteed to have a particular type of output, so you don't need to write extra checks for zero length inputs.

**Benchmarks**

`vapply` can be a bit faster because it already knows what format it should be expecting the results in.

```
input1.long <- rep(input1,10000)

library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(
  sapply(input1.long, findD ),
  vapply(input1.long, findD, "" )
)
library(ggplot2)
library(taRifx) # autoplot.microbenchmark is moving to the microbenchmark package in the next release so this should be unnecessary soon
autoplot(m)
```

[image: autoplot]

Answer (score 15):

The extra key strokes involved with `vapply` could save you time debugging confusing results later. If the function you're calling can return different datatypes, `vapply` should certainly be used.

One example that comes to mind would be `sqlQuery` in the `RODBC` package. If there's an error executing a query, this function returns a `character` vector with the message. So, for example, say you're trying to iterate over a vector of table names `tnames` and select the max value from the numeric column 'NumCol' in each table with:

```
sapply(tnames, 
   function(tname) sqlQuery(cnxn, paste("SELECT MAX(NumCol) FROM", tname))[[1]])
```

If all the table names are valid, this would result in a `numeric` vector. But if one of the table names happens to change in the database and the query fails, the results are going to be coerced into mode `character`. Using `vapply` with `FUN.VALUE=numeric(1)`, however, will stop the error here and prevent it from popping up somewhere down the line---or worse, not at all.

Answer (score 14):

If you always want your result to be something in particular...e.g. a logical vector.  `vapply` makes sure this happens but `sapply` does not necessarily do so.

```
a<-vapply(NULL, is.factor, FUN.VALUE=logical(1))
b<-sapply(NULL, is.factor)

is.logical(a)
is.logical(b)
```

Comment: i think the most obvious thing to do is `logical(1)` in this case, as FALSE looks like it sets an option to “OFF” instead of specifying a type