# Efficiently create dataframe from strings containing key-value pairs

Tags: performance, algorithm, r

I would like to ask you for efficiency suggestions for a specific coding problem in R. I have a string vector in the following style:

```
[1] "HGVSc=ENST00000495576.1:n.820-1G>A;INTRON=1/1;CANONICAL=YES"
[2] "DISTANCE=2179"                                              
[3] "HGVSc=ENST00000466430.1:n.911C>T;EXON=4/4;CANONICAL=YES"    
[4] "DISTANCE=27;CANONICAL=YES;common"
```

In each element of the vector, the single entries are separated with a `;` and MOST of the single entries have the format `KEY=VALUE`. However, there are also some entries, which only have the format `KEY` (see "common" in [4]). In this example, there are 15 different keys and not every key appears in each element of the vector. The 15 different keys are:

```
names <- c('ENSP','HGVS','DOMAINS','EXON','INTRON', 'HGVSp', 'HGVSc','CANONICAL','GMAF','DISTANCE', 'HGNC', 'CCDS', 'SIFT', 'PolyPhen', 'common')
```

From this vector I would like to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ENSP HGVS DOMAINS EXON INTRON HGVSp                        HGVSc CANONICAL
1    -    -       -    -    1/1     - ENST00000495576.1:n.820-1G>A       YES
2    -    -       -    -      -     -                            -         -
3    -    -       -  4/4      -     -   ENST00000466430.1:n.911C>T       YES
4    -    -       -    -      -     -                            -       YES
GMAF DISTANCE HGNC CCDS SIFT PolyPhen common
1    -        -    -    -    -        -      -
2    -     2179    -    -    -        -      -
3    -        -    -    -    -        -      -
4    -       27    -    -    -        -    YES
```

I wrote this function to solve the problem:

```
unlist.info <- function(names, column){
  info.mat <- matrix(rep('-', length(column)*length(names)), nrow=length(column), ncol=length(names), dimnames=list(c(), names))
  info.mat <- as.data.frame(info.mat, stringsAsFactors=F)

  for (i in 1:length(column)){
    info <- unlist(strsplit(column[i], "\\;"))
    for (e in info){
      e <- unlist(strsplit(e, "\\="))
      j <- which(names == e[1])
      if (length(e) > 1){
        # KEY=VALUE. The value might contain a = as well
        value <- paste(e[2:length(e)], collapse='=')
        info.mat[i,j] <- value
      }else{
        # only KEY
        info.mat[i,j] <- 'YES'
      }
    }
  }
  return(info.mat)
}
```

And then I call:

```
mat <- unlist.info(names, vector)
```

Even though this works, it is really slow. Also I am handling vectors with over 100.000 entries. Now I realize that looping is inelegant and inefficient in R and I am familiar with the concept of applying functions to data frames. However, since every entry of the vector contains a different subset of `KEY=VALUE` or `KEY` entries I could not come up with a more efficient function.

Comment: As a first step I would `split` on the semicolons.  Then use [tag:regex]s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

Recreate the data:

```
x <- c(
  "HGVSc=ENST00000495576.1:n.820-1G>A;INTRON=1//1;CANONICAL=YES",
  "DISTANCE=2179",
  "HGVSc=ENST00000466430.1:n.911C>T;EXON=4//4;CANONICAL=YES",
  "DISTANCE=27;CANONICAL=YES;common"
)
```

Create a named vector with your desired names. This is used for fast lookup later:

```
names <- setNames(1:15, c('ENSP','HGVS','DOMAINS','EXON','INTRON', 'HGVSp', 'HGVSc','CANONICAL','GMAF','DISTANCE', 'HGNC', 'CCDS', 'SIFT', 'PolyPhen', 'common'))
```

Create a helper function that assigns each variable to the correct position in a matrix. Then use `lapply` and `strsplit`:

```
assign <- function(x, names){
  xx <- sapply(x, function(i)if(length(i)==2L) i else c(i, "YES"))
  z <- rep(NA, length(names))
  z[names[xx[1, ]]] <- xx[2, ]
  z
}

sx <- lapply(strsplit(x, ";"), strsplit, "=")
ret <- t(sapply(sx, assign, names))
colnames(ret) <- names(names)
ret
```

The results:

```
     ENSP HGVS DOMAINS EXON   INTRON HGVSp HGVSc                          CANONICAL GMAF DISTANCE HGNC
[1,] NA   NA   NA      NA     "1//1" NA    "ENST00000495576.1:n.820-1G>A" "YES"     NA   NA       NA  
[2,] NA   NA   NA      NA     NA     NA    NA                             NA        NA   "2179"   NA  
[3,] NA   NA   NA      "4//4" NA     NA    "ENST00000466430.1:n.911C>T"   "YES"     NA   NA       NA  
[4,] NA   NA   NA      NA     NA     NA    NA                             "YES"     NA   "27"     NA  
     CCDS SIFT PolyPhen common
[1,] NA   NA   NA       NA    
[2,] NA   NA   NA       NA    
[3,] NA   NA   NA       NA    
[4,] NA   NA   NA       "YES"
```

Comment: Great answer.  I'd suggest `vapply` over `sapply` here though.  [Faster and safer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12340888/636656)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman yes, I agree. `vapply` is just one of many ways to optimise this further. Generally I use `sapply` to solve the initial problem and then optimise from there.

Comment: What, you didn't perfectly over-optimize your Stackoverflow answer on the first try?  What are they paying you all that money for then? :-)

Comment: @Andrie, thank you very much, Andrie. This is a great idea. I made some minor modifications to adress some exeptions, but still your code is about 60 times faster than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another, faster, solution taking advantage of the original pairings...

```
##                   test elapsed replications relative average
## 2    thell_solution(x)    0.37         1000    1.000 0.00037
## 3   andrie_solution(x)    1.04         1000    2.811 0.00104
## 1 original_solution(x)    2.61         1000    7.054 0.00261
```

Since pairing[1] always gets assigned pairing[2] except with the final bool (… not that I understand why that one flag is treated differently in the original string vector …) we can take advantage of the sequence and the fact that the vector will assign NA when a name is given without a value ( ie: x[5] == NA ) and we also have no need to call names multiple times.  And since strsplit uses regex we can do alternation.

```
# Let `x` be as @Andrie made it in his answer.  Let `names` be as you had
# in the original question.

# A pre-built dummy record and empty list.
na.record <- setNames(rep(NA, time = length(names)), names)
y <- list()

do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x, "(;|=)"), FUN = function(x) {
    x_seq <- seq.int(to = length(x), by = 2)
    y[x[x_seq]] <- x[x_seq + 1]
    y[is.na(y)] <- "YES"
    na.record[x[x_seq]] <- y
    na.record
}))


##      ENSP HGVS DOMAINS EXON   INTRON HGVSp HGVSc                         
## [1,] NA   NA   NA      NA     "1//1" NA    "ENST00000495576.1:n.820-1G>A"
## [2,] NA   NA   NA      NA     NA     NA    NA                            
## [3,] NA   NA   NA      "4//4" NA     NA    "ENST00000466430.1:n.911C>T"  
## [4,] NA   NA   NA      NA     NA     NA    NA                            
##      CANONICAL GMAF DISTANCE HGNC CCDS SIFT PolyPhen common
## [1,] "YES"     NA   NA       NA   NA   NA   NA       NA    
## [2,] NA        NA   "2179"   NA   NA   NA   NA       NA    
## [3,] "YES"     NA   NA       NA   NA   NA   NA       NA    
## [4,] "YES"     NA   "27"     NA   NA   NA   NA       "YES"
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, as well. All your contributions have been very helpful for me.