# R: How to nicely divide all element of a vector by the sum of all the other element

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I want to make a function that replaces all elements of a vector by the value of each element divided by the sum of all the *other* elements. I created that function but I am sure there is a better and simpler way to write it:

```
v1=runif(10)
v2=c()
l=1:length(v1)
for(i in l){
    v2=c(v2,(v1[i]/sum(v1[l[l!=i]])))
}
v1=v2
```

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on this site so I am voting to migrate this question to SO. Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour and http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to learn more about this site.

Comment: thanks for moving it, I am not yet really used with all the SO policies, my bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
v / (sum(v) - v)
```

Comment: Nice and thank you! It's indeed a really more easy, logical and quick way. But anyway thanks to @Tim I discovered `seq_along` and `vapply` which are two functions that I often look for.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this would be to use `vapply` function (see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply)):

```
myfun <- function(x) {
   vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i] / sum(x[-i]), numeric(1))
}

myfun(1:10)
## [1] 0.01851852 0.03773585 0.05769231 0.07843137 0.10000000 0.12244898 0.14583333 0.17021277 0.19565217 0.22222222
```

The `for`-loops are generally slow and clumsy in R so are better to be avoided if not necessary. However, even if you wanted the `for`-loop for some reasons, small improvements are possible:

```
forfun <- function(x) {
  out <- numeric() # you know in advance that it will be a numeric vector
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    # R treats everything as a vector, so you can assign values
    # to every i-th element of any vector (even the empty one)
    # while concatenating c(x, x[i] / sum(x[-i])) slows things
    out[i] <- x[i] / sum(x[-i])
  }
  out
}
```

Now, let's compare the performance (`forfun1` is your initial code, `forfun2` is the one with `for`-loop but after corrections, and `myfun` is the `vapply` version):

```
> benchmark(forfun1(runif(1000)), forfun2(runif(1000)), myfun(runif(1000)))
                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 forfun1(runif(1000))          100    1.46    1.207      1.47        0         NA        NA
2 forfun2(runif(1000))          100    1.30    1.074      1.29        0         NA        NA
3   myfun(runif(1000))          100    1.21    1.000      1.20        0         NA        NA
```

as you can see, it is not only the matter of simplicity of the code, but also it's performance.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with `apply` but it works only with matrices and array, and I was missing the `seq_along` function, which will save me lot of useless `for loop`.