# Can vapply() be used with a variable-length FUN.VALUE?

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to follow [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply) and use `vapply()` instead of `sapply()` inside functions, but find the type checking from `vapply()` to be too inflexible when wanting a fixed length.

Let's say I want something like this:

```
list1 <- list(l1_one = 1:3, l1_two = letters[1:3])
list2 <- list(l2_one = 4:6, l2_two = letters[4:6], l2_three = 10:12)
list_12 <- list(list1, list2)

sapply(list_12, names)
# [[1]]
# [1] "l1_one" "l1_two"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "l2_one"   "l2_two"   "l2_three"
```

Is there a way to allow variable lengths, but check that the return is of mode "character", and at least one in length? Clearly this does not work:

```
vapply(list_12, names, character(2))
# Error in vapply(list_12, names, character(2)) : values must be length 2,
# but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 3
```

Comment: No, that's not possible with vapply. If you want checks write a function that includes them.

Answer (score 0):

`sapply` is unsafe because its return type is not stable. If you know your return type you can safely use `vapply`. If not, like in your case, simply use `lapply` instead.

For your example:

```
list1 <- list(l1_one = 1:3, l1_two = letters[1:3])
list2 <- list(l2_one = 4:6, l2_two = letters[4:6], l2_three = 10:12)
list_12 <- list(list1, list2)

lapply(list_12, names) # always list() return type
```