# Using vapply instead of sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I am reading Advanced R by Hadley available at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html. He talks about the difference between `sapply` and `vapply`. My question is relating to using `vapply` instead of `sapply`, which he doesn't discuss further in his example.

Here's his code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = Sys.time() + 1:10)
sapply(df2, class)
```

This returns

```
$x
[1] "integer"

$y
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

However, when I run `vapply`, I get an error.

```
vapply(df2, class, character(1))
```

Error:

```
Error in vapply(df2, class, character(1)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 2
```

I have two questions:

**Question:1)** When I replace character(1) with character(2), it gives me the following error message:

```
vapply(df2, class, character(2))
Error in vapply(df2, class, character(2)) : values must be length 2,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

Why does this happen?

**Question:2)** How do I use `vapply` instead of `sapply`?

I am learning R so your answers will help me understand R at a deeper level. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Question 1:

The error with `character(2)` is because the character vector `"integer"` is only of length 1 and rightly fails the consistency check against the expected result of character vector of length 2.

#### Question 2:

`vapply()` is there as a [safer version of `sapply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply?rq=1) as it makes sure you only get back what you expect from each application of `FUN`. It is also safer I guess because the output from `vapply()` is consistent - you don't get a vector or a matrix or a list. You get a vector for length 1 returned sub-components and an array otherwise.

In the specific example you give, you can't use `vapply()` as what is returned by `class` isn't consistent. You have to know or expect certain output and `vapply()` fails if the output from a call to `FUN` doesn't match what it expects.

In this instance, I suppose you could do

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = Sys.time() + 1:10)
vapply(df2, FUN = function(x) paste(class(x), collapse = "; "),
       FUN.VALUE = character(1))

> vapply(df2, FUN = function(x) paste(class(x), collapse = "; "),
+        FUN.VALUE = character(1))
                x                 y 
        "integer" "POSIXct; POSIXt"
```

but whether that is useful to you or not is a different matter.

Really, using `vapply()` comes down to knowing what to expect from `FUN` and wanting to only ever get that output. If you don't know or can't control it, you are probably better off with `lapply()`.