# Converting a vector of characters including the "^" operator to numeric

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers and characters that are treated as characters, for example:

```
mix <- c("50", ">10^4", "<10", "325")
```

I understand how to strip off the `>` and `<` and apply `as.numeric()`. However, this results in a `NA` value for `"10^4"`.

I've tried to use `eval("10^4")` however this doesn't work and simply returns the character.

Currently, my function is:

```
f_convert2numeric <- function(vec){
  nvec = eval(as.numeric(gsub(">","",gsub("<","",vec))))
  return(nvec)
}
```

Is there any way to add in this ability to convert characters using `^` to numeric? Preferably in base `R` but happy with alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
sapply(gsub("[<>]", "", mix), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

gives:

> ```
> [1]    50 10000    10   325
> ```

---

If you omit `USE.NAMES = FALSE`, you will get a named vector:

> ```
>    50  10^4    10   325 
>    50 10000    10   325
> ```

---

It might be worthwhile to consider `vapply` over `sapply` ([see here for an explanation why this is safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply)):

```
vapply(gsub("[<>]", "", mix), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)),
       FUN.VALUE = 1, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `parse()` was a very vital component I was missing! And appreciate the tidying of my clunky code!