# What is the `vapply` equivalent for `mapply`?

Tags: r, mapply

In base R, [`sapply` has a safer (and sometimes faster) variant called `vapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply). `mapply` is a multivariate version of `sapply`.

I am running into an edge case issue when using `mapply` (length-0 input *to `mapply`* (not to `FUN`) yields a `list()` instead of `integer(0)` ).

Is there an `vapply` equivalent of `mapply` that allows to specify `FUN.VALUE` (the expected return value type/dimension)?

If not, what is the the recommended pattern in those situations?

A toy example:

```
size_of_union <- function(A, B) length(union(A, B))
# normal case:
x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
mapply(size_of_union, x, y)
#> [1] 3 1 1

# edge-case:
x <- integer(0)
y <- integer(0)
mapply(size_of_union, x, y)
#> list()  # integer(0) would be desired here
```

A more contrived toy example:

```r
range_of_intersect <- function(A, B) range(intersect(A, B))

x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
mapply(range_of_intersect, x, y)
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    2  Inf
#> [2,]    3    2 -Inf


x <- numeric(0)
y <- numeric(0)
mapply(range_of_intersect, x, y)
#> list() # structure(numeric(0), .Dim = c(2L, 0L)) would be desired
```

Comment: You cannot have a `vapply` that will return `integer(0)` and `integer(1)` etc. in this case you will have to rewrite your FUN so as to ensure you do not return elements of length 0. Note that if you are returning an empty list, thats because your function does return NULL

Comment: Just to point out, there is no multivariate equivalent for `vapply`. but you could try `purrr:::pmap_int`. Note that if you are looking for non-existent functions, you are doing something incorectly

Comment: You also missed my point. You definitely cannot use `X` like this. if `X` is just `character(0)` no need of `vapply`. Just `as.integer(X)` should do. Now try having `X = list(character(0), character(1))` and run your code. It wont work. *The return value for length-0 inputs to `FUN` (`add_scalar`) DOES matter*. You specified that it should be `integer(1)` for all the cases of `X` therefore you cannot mix the return values to have some with `integer(0)` and others with `integer(1)`. Try any example with `X` being a list.

Comment: @Onyambu I think it wasn't clear from my question that this was about length-0 input *to `mapply`* not *to `FUN`*. I think it is clear now and will remove my earlier comments with which I was trying to clarify.

Comment: What about `as.integer(Map(size_of_union, x, y))` ?

Comment: @moodymudskipper
 that works for my use-case of a function returning a scalar (minus the probably minor speed benefits and build-in sanity check of `vapply`), I added a more contrived example now to make my case.

Comment: you might iterate on the index, and then you can use `vapply()`, would this work ? `vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) range_of_intersect(x[[i]], y[[i]]), numeric(2))`

Comment: I went along and answered

Comment: Nice, @moodymudskipper. *Now*, I think, a combination of your comments would make an accepted answer ;) perhaps with a quote about the issue from `?Map`?  (let me know if you need another hint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first case you might use `as.integer(Map(size_of_union, x, y))`

More generally you can still use `vapply()` but you'll need to loop on the index rather than on parallel vectors :

```r
size_of_union <- function(A, B) length(union(A, B))
x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) size_of_union(x[[i]], y[[i]]), integer(1))
#> [1] 3 1 1

x <- integer(0)
y <- integer(0)
vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) size_of_union(x[[i]], y[[i]]), integer(1))
#> integer(0)

range_of_intersect <- function(A, B) range(intersect(A, B))
x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
res <- vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) range_of_intersect(x[[i]], y[[i]]), numeric(2))
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
res
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    2  Inf
#> [2,]    3    2 -Inf
dput(res)
#> structure(c(3, 3, 2, 2, Inf, -Inf), dim = 2:3)

x <- numeric(0)
y <- numeric(0)
res <- vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) range_of_intersect(x[[i]], y[[i]]), numeric(2))
res
#>     
#> [1,]
#> [2,]
dput(res)
#> structure(numeric(0), dim = c(2L, 0L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I accepted your answer since it was the "most helpful in finding my solution". See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76690733/1870254) for a slightly better approach.

Comment: This is clever, feel free to accept your own answer if you feel it answers the question better. I'm happy that I could help

Answer (score 2):

In base R, there is no version of `mapply()` I know of where you could enforce the output value type. You can look into using the [`pmap_*()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pmap.html) functions from the package `purrr`.

E.g., for your example:

```r
size_of_union <- function(A, B) length(union(A, B))

x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
purrr::pmap_int(list(x, y), size_of_union)
#> [1] 3 1 1

x <- integer(0)
y <- integer(0)
purrr::pmap_int(list(x, y), size_of_union)
#> integer(0) # purrr::pmap_int handles edge-case correctly
```

#### A different way of looking at it

Your edge-case is not really about data types, it is about zero-length inputs. `vapply()` probably just creates an empty vector on the basis of `FUN.VALUE` in order to put the results inside it, but then it does not iterate at all (the input is of length zero) and so it remains empty.

`mapply()` works differently, creating a list first and then coercing into an atomic vector/matrix if `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` (the default). So the placeholder is an empty `list()`, rather than an empty atomic vector.

This is also why the `stopifnot()` does not throw an error on zero-length input - it is never called in the first place because no iterations happened.

I would just do `as.integer(mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = TRUE))` which converts `list()` if it occurs to `integer(0)`.

So: If the question is "How to solve this edge case?" then this is it. If the question is "How to make base R behave like purrr?" (ensuring all resulting elements are of correct type) then I don't think there is a generally accepted pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that works well but relies on external packages.

Comment: That's right. Would you like to add to the question the "recommended pattern" has to be using base R?

Comment: (I) I added another example but cant figure out how to make it work with `purr`, using `purrr::pmap_vec` with `.ptype` ??

Comment: (II)  `as.integer(mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = TRUE))` will also *not* error if `FUN` always yields a vector of the same size (and `mapply` thus a matrix which `as.integer` silently convert to a vector, so `as.integer(mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE))`, or, equivalently `as.integer(Map(...))` would be slightly safer.

Comment: (III) re: "add to question" haha not a requirement but I doubt that making a package and its dependencies a dependency for such a simple function can be the "recommended pattern" (if one anyway depends on any tidyverse packages, sure!)

Comment: (I) sorry, don't know either. (II) I guess that's right, although weirdness can still happen, hard to say how this would behave in a non-toy code. (III) Not sure how many people would stumble upon this thread and think, "How trivial, definitely not worth a dependency!"

Comment: One more observation: While Mudskipper's solution is clever, it still bothers me a little. If the problem is input length, should it really be the iterator function's job to try to account for it?

Answer (score 1):

I find a combination of `vapply` and `mapply`/`Map` easier to use than vapply over indices.

Here, `mapply` (with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`)/`Map` maps the inputs to a list of return values (turning the multivariate into univariate problem) while `vapply` (with `FUN = identity`) only takes care of checking of / providing return value types and appropriately simplifying the output.

Use either directly with either of:

```r
vapply(mapply(my_fun, my_params1, my_params2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = my_restype))
```

```r
vapply(Map(my_fun, my_params1, my_params2), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = my_restype))
```

Or using either of the following shorthands:

```r
vMap <- function(FUN, FUN.VALUE, ...)
  vapply(Map(FUN, ...), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = FUN.VALUE)
```

```r
vmapply <- function(FUN, FUN.VALUE, ..., MoreArgs = NULL)
  vapply(mapply(FUN = FUN, ..., MoreArgs = MoreArgs, SIMPLIFY = FALSE), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = FUN.VALUE)
```

Simple example:

```r
size_of_union <- function(A, B) length(union(A, B))
## normal case:
x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
vapply(Map(size_of_union, x , y), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = integer(1))
#> [1] 3 1 1

## edge-case:
x <- integer(0)
y <- integer(0)
vapply(Map(size_of_union, x , y), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = integer(1))
#> integer(0)
```

More contrived example:

```r
range_of_intersect <- function(A, B) range(intersect(A, B))

## normal case:
x <- list(1:3, 2, 3)
y <- list(3, 2, numeric(0)) 
vapply(Map(range_of_intersect, x , y), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = numeric(2))
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    2  Inf
#> [2,]    3    2 -Inf

## edge-case:
x <- numeric(0)
y <- numeric(0)
vapply(Map(range_of_intersect, x , y), FUN = identity, FUN.VALUE = numeric(2))
#>     
#> [1,]
#> [2,]
```

from `?Map` (emphasis mine):

> Map is a simple wrapper to mapply which does not attempt to simplify
> the result, similar to Common Lisp's mapcar (with arguments being
> recycled, however). **Future versions may allow some control of the
> result type.**

This hints that a multivariate version of `vapply` is not yet implemented in base R. And given the rare need for it and the minimal extra effort incurred by using the approach presented in this answer, it probably never will be.

Thanks to @moodymudskipper for leading me to this solution!