# Under what circumstances is `vapply()` slower than `sapply()`?

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply, sapply

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) for the `*apply()` functions states:

> `vapply` is similar to `sapply`, but has a pre-specified type of return value, so it can be safer (and ***sometimes*** faster) to use. *[Emphasis mine.]*

It makes sense to me why it would be faster- less time wasted checking types - but, given that they could have said something like *'`vapply()` is as fast or faster than `sapply()`'*, but chose not to, I interpreted their choice of *sometimes faster* as them potentially meaning *'for most tasks `vapply()` is on average faster, but in some cases it could be on average the same speed, or in others even *slower*'*- which seems quite odd to me. Why would it ever be slower? Advanced R [states](https://bookdown.org/content/d1e53ac9-28ce-472f-bc2c-f499f18264a3/loops.html#apply-family) *'`vapply()` is faster than `sapply()`'*, which is fairly categorical, in contrast.

Am I misunderstanding this, or are there circumstances in which `vapply()` is slower than `sapply()`, and if so, what are they?

For example the rationale could be because of a difference in garbage collection, or the speed with which certain types are processed, or allocating memory or something else (these are wild guesses).

###### Research I've done:

Surprisingly, I couldn't find addressing this online, on StackOverflow or elsewhere. There's plenty of questions that [reference vapply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/4145280), and [its safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply). In a [few](https://rpubs.com/edwardcooper/faster_r_codes_2) [comparisons](https://uscbiostats.github.io/software-dev-site/handbook-slow-patterns.html#sapply()_vs_vapply()), while `vapply()` was as fast or faster than `sapply()`, there were many iterations which are faster than the slowest `vapply()` iteration (and one where `apply()` was significantly faster than either `lapply()` or `vapply()`. So long story short, I'm a bit lost!

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "but sometimes faster implies sometimes it can be slower" No, it doesn't. The negation of `<` is `>=` and not `>`. I doubt that you can construct an example where `vapply` is significantly slower in a meaningful way.

Comment: I don't think the implication you've drawn is correct.  I read it as essentially saying that `vapply()` is as at least as fast as `sapply()` but it can be faster, not that it is sometimes slower.

Comment: @Roland that was essentially the question! I wasn't sure if it was correct to assume that they meant to say, *'it is always as fast or faster than lapply'*, though I guess if that's what they meant I can't see why they wouldn't have just said that (or words to that effect) instead? Thank you for your message btw!

Comment: My hunch is that `vapply` cannot be significantly slower than `sapply`  but it can significantly faster. I think it depedens on whether we use `sapply`s `simplify = TRUE` argument. If set `FALSE` there is no reason `sapply` should be slower then `vapply`. Put the other way round: if `simplify = FALSE` there is no reason why `vapply` should be significantly faster than `sapply`.

Comment: that seems reasonable @RitchieSacramento, thank you for commenting. I found [a comparison](https://rpubs.com/edwardcooper/faster_r_codes_2) which included vapply from USC in the time between posting the question and now, which has some interesting comparisons. In one (the second graph) apply is significantly faster than vapply (but still roughly the same speed as lapply)

Comment: @Roland I updated the question to make my logic less faulty. Thank you again for your comment! :-)

Comment: After your update I think it’s clear that you have a gap in understanding benchmarks. The reason we repeat benchmarks is that there are *external circumstances* which affect individual timings. You will *always* see some variation, and the reason that some of the measures of `vapply` are slower than some of those of `sapply` has nothing to do with `vapply` with `sapply`. It is *noise*, caused by other things running on the same computer in the background, which cannot be avoided. In a perfect benchmark, all points would fall on the same time, without any spread.

Comment: (This is assuming that the functions are deterministic, and that we are running on the same input; but this is the case here. In rare cases, benchmarks are run on variable input and *that* can cause functions to have variable runtimes; but this is not generally visualised in a single graph without explicit labelling, and doing so would be misleading.)

Comment: thanks for your messages @KonradRudolph! That is part of the thing I was trying to get at with the comments: looking at the graphs, seeing overlaps, differences, and not knowing the source of those differences, it's hard to tell if it is something intrinsic to the functions/the code, or some external factor. And you saying that helps clear it up!

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wasn't sure if maybe there was something different in say, how `lapply` and `vapply` handle garbage collection, or perhaps `vapply` preallocates memory for the output, and in some circumstances, say if the output was to be very large, this would slow things down (not saying this is what vapply does, just a wild guess). But given that I couldn't find a single comment about this line of the docs on the internet (it's surprisingly hard to ask a question that doesn't have a single thing on google), it seemed worth asking, if at the cost of seeming stupid. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Mark Yes, that actually make sense, my initial comment glossed over these potential differences.

Comment: Don't get hung up on semantics. After looking at the source code of these functions, you should expect `vapply` to be faster. I have never studied computer science but I wouldn't be surprised if there is a general principle confirming that it should be faster (assuming optimal implementation of the algorithms).

Comment: @Roland thank you for doing that! :-) I sometimes misunderstand the semantic meaning of writing, so this is a relief. Hopefully we're not missing anything! I might try and ask the R mailing group about changing this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The checks which make `vapply()` fast are not free

In order to contrive circumstances where `vapply()` is slower than `sapply()`, let's look at the [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed51d34ec195b89462a8531b9ef30b7b72e47204/src/library/base/R/sapply.R#L67). Most of the work in `sapply()` is done by `lapply()`. The [C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed51d34ec195b89462a8531b9ef30b7b72e47204/doc/manual/R-exts.c#L175) for `lapply()` is quite simple. The relevant part is (comments mine):

```c
// Allocate a vector for the output with the length of the input vector/list
ans = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, n));
// Loop through input list, apply relevant function and 
// assign result to each respective element of the output list
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    defineVar(install("x"), VECTOR_ELT(list, i), rho);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, i, eval(expr, rho));
}
```

Essentially this creates an output list of the same length as the input list, iterating through it to set every element to the result of the user-provided function applied to each element of the input. `sapply()` then runs the result through [`simplify2array()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed51d34ec195b89462a8531b9ef30b7b72e47204/src/library/base/R/sapply.R#L27).

Conversely, the C [code for `vapply()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed51d34ec195b89462a8531b9ef30b7b72e47204/src/main/apply.c#L95) does a lot more work. A lot of this is optimisation which makes it quicker than `sapply()`, e.g. allocating an atomic vector immediately as the output, rather than allocating a list and then simplifying into a vector. However,  it also contains this:

```c
// Check that the result is the correct length for the output vector/list
if (length(val) != commonLen)
error(_("values must be length %d,\n but FUN(X[[%d]]) result is length %d"),
        commonLen, i+1, length(val));
```

We tell `vapply()` the length and type of the output. This means that if, for example, if we tell `vapply()` that the output is `integer(1)`, it needs to check that each iteration produces an integer vector of length 1.

### A case where those checks are expensive

One way to create costly checks is to return a value where checking the length is expensive. Consider the simple example:

```r
lapply(1, \(i) seq(1e9))
```

`lapply()` will run very quickly here. `seq(1e9)` produces an `ALTREP`, an [alternate representation](https://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/%7Eluke/talks/uiowa-2018.pdf). This means that rather than having to allocate a vector of length `1e9`, it allocates a much smaller object which essentially holds the start value, end value and increment. However, the docs for `ALTREP` state:

> To existing C code ALTREP objects look like ordinary R objects.

This means `vapply()` does not know that that this is an `ALTREP`, and so it needs to check the length in a very costly way (much more costly than just running `length()` in R, which knows what an `ALTREP` is).

`sapply()` also has to do something costly. It basically does this:

```
simplify2array(list(seq(1e9)))
```

This creates a one-column `matrix` with `1e9` rows, i.e. it evaluates the `ALTREP` into a standard integer vector, so it allocates a large vector in RAM.

So `vapply()` and `sapply()` both have to do something considerably more expensive than `lapply()`. The question is: which is costlier?

### Benchmarking the contrived case

Let's put this to the test:

```r
results <- bench::mark(
    min_iterations = 3,
    max_iterations = 100,
    check = FALSE,
    time_unit = "s",
    lapply = {
        lapply(1, \(i) seq(1e9))
    },
    sapply = {
        sapply(1, \(i) seq(1e9))
    },
    vapply = {
        vapply(1, \(i) seq(1e9), numeric(1e9))
    }
)
```

#### Results

```
  expression         min     median  `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 lapply      0.00000954  0.0000277 31233.            0B   0        100     0    0.00320
2 sapply     23.3        27.9           0.0309    11.2GB   0.0309     3     3   97.0    
3 vapply     71.8        79.6           0.0126    22.4GB   0.0251     3     6  239.
```

We can see here that `vapply()` is substantially slower than `sapply()`. There are some caveats: these tests are just on my PC, and it was so slow that I only did three iterations. Also, I did have to do some playing around to get to here. With a vector of less than length `1e9`, `vapply()` is faster than `sapply()`.

#### Plot of results

```r
ggplot2::autoplot(results) +
    labs(title = "Comparison of results", y = "Time (log scale)", x = "Expression")
```

Note that time is on a log scale.

[image]

It is worth pointing out that, fun as it was to engineer this situation, this is not typical.  In the vast majority of tasks for which R is used, `vapply()` is likely to be considerably faster than `sapply()`. Also, as you know, there are other benefits, such as that `vapply()` ensures the return type is guaranteed.

Comment: this is really incredible Sam... you are incredible. Thank you!!!