# R apply: loses dimname names

Tags: r, matrix, apply

this is a simple enough question that I'm suprised I can't find any reference to anyone having asked it before. It's not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469504/access-and-preserve-list-names-in-lapply-function), nor is it covered by [this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-July/058045.html).

I have a 4-d matrix (dimensions 16x10x15x39) with named dimnames (*it's what happens when you `cast` a dataframe from, e.g. a csv. You get to the names of the dimnames with `names(dimnames(matrix))`*)

I then want to replace the columns (i.e. the first dimension) with fractions of the row total, so I do this:

```
matrix2 <- apply(matrix1, c(2,3,4), function(x){x/sum(x)})
```

But now `names(dimnames(matrix2))` is blank for the first dimension. The other dimname names have been preserved.

So: how can I run `apply` over a matrix with named dimnames and keep the names of all the remaining dimensions?

### A reproducable example

Here's simple example of the problem. Just run the whole code and look at the last two lines.

```
x <- data.frame(
  name=c("bob","james","sarah","bob","james",
         "sarah","bob","james","sarah","bob",
         "james","sarah"),
  year=c("1995","1995","1995","1995","1995",
         "1995","2005","2005","2005","2005",
         "2005","2005"),
  sample_num=c("sample1","sample1","sample1",
               "sample2","sample2","sample2",
               "sample1","sample1","sample1",
               "sample2","sample2","sample2"),
  value=c(1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4)
  )
x <- cast(x, sample_num ~ name ~ year)
x_fractions <- apply(y,c(2,3),function(x){x / sum(x)})

names(dimnames(x))
names(dimnames(x_fractions))
```

Comment: I wonder why you need to `cast` the data.frame. It's usually better to work with long data format.

Comment: Hi Roland. I agree, the `cast` looks odd, but there are some sensible display reasons for doing it like that.

Comment: `apply` coerces its outputs to `as.vector` , so maybe the real question is "how did any dimnames survive the `apply` process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but I think `sweep` function fits well for your goal. Try:

```
result <- sweep(test, c(2,3,4), colSums(test), FUN='/')
```

Where `test` is the array created by @user2068776. `dimnames` are preserved.

```
dimnames(result)
$a
[1] "a1" "a2"

$b
[1] "b1" "b2"

$c
[1] "c1" "c2"

$d
[1] "d1" "d2"
```

Comment: Thanks Jilber. That certainly does the job! Any insights into the use of apply w.r.t. dimname names? i.e. what's going on or not going on when the first name gets dropped?

Answer (score 1):

It is really ambiguous to answer question without a reproducible example.
I answer this question, because producing an example here is interesting.

```
dat <- array(rnorm(16*10*15*39))
dim(dat) <- c(16,10,15,39)
dimnames(dat) <- lapply(c(16,10,15,39),
                        function(x) paste('a',sample(1:1000,x,rep=F),sep=''))
dat2 <- apply(dat, c(2,3,4), function(x){x/sum(x)})
identical(dimnames(dat2) ,dimnames(dat))
[1] TRUE
```

I get the same dimanmes for dat and dat2. So surely I miss something here.

Comment: Done a reproducable example. Sorry for not putting one first time around!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behavior using a non-casted array. Could you provide a **reproducable** example of what your dataframe/array actually looks like?
Otherwise it is difficult to find out where the problem is.

Here is the code I used for testing this:

```
# example
a <- c(1,2,11,22)
b <- c(3,4,33,44)
c <- c(5,6,55,66)
d <- c(7,8,77,88)

test <- array(c(a,b,c,d), c(2,2,2,2), dimnames=list(
a=c("a1","a2"),
b=c("b1","b2"),
c=c("c1","c2"),
d=c("d1","d2") )
)
dimnames(test)
names(dimnames(test))

# apply
test2 <- apply(test, c(2,3,4), function(x){
  entry <- sum(x)
})
dimnames(test2)
names(dimnames(test2))
```

Sorry for the comment "diguised" as an answer. I am new to SO and as it seems you need a higher rep to post comments.

Edit: Your `dimnames` might get lost, because for whatever reason the function your defined produces unnamed results. You can try saving `x/sum(x)` as an object (like I did) and then naming that object inside your function. I skipped the last part, because for me there were no missing `names` / `dimnames`

Comment: Sorry. Reproducable example provided!